# Красная вертикальная линия по всей высоте сайта. Как убрать?

Tags: wordpress

Сегодня на [сайте](http://www.AlkoNarkoStop.com.ua) появилась красная вертикальная линия по всей высоте сайта. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ее убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе нужно убрать или заменить `http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/-e1423758635687.jpg` (изображение). Посмотри внимательно, есть красная точка (центр)!